# Assign a string a value to a variable depending of a rand(1,9)

Tags: php

I'm trying to assign a value to a variable and I was wondering if there were something more convenient and short that the usual if / else if way.

```
$typeofvariable = rand (1,9);
if ($typeofvariable == 1) {
$stringvalue = "type a";
}
else if ($typeofvariable == 2) {
$stringe value == "type b";
}
.......
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `$map = ['type a', 'type b', ...]; $string = $map[array_rand($map)];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is how stack works.

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $map = array("type a", "type b", ...);
    $string = $map[array_rand($map)];

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`switch`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statement

```
$typeofvariable = rand (1,9);
switch ($typeofvariable) {
    case 1:
        $stringvalue = "type a";
        break;
    case 2:
        $stringvalue = "type b";
        break;
    case 3:
        // etc..
        break;
    default:
        // Code to be executed if non of above.
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `switch()` like this:

```
<?php
$typeofvariable = rand (1,9);
switch ($typeofvariable) {
    case 1:
        //code to be executed if $typeofvariable=1;
        break;
    case 2:
        //code to be executed if $typeofvariable=2;
        break;
    case 3:
        //code to be executed if $typeofvariable=3;
        break;
    ...
    default:
        code to be executed if $typeofvariable is different from all labels;
} 
?>
```